# For GCP how to scp file from one node to another node?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh

On GCP I have a nodepool for our kubernetes cluster and I can ssh to any of the node in the nodepool. However when I tried the scp command on one of the node to try to copy a file from current node to another node. It says:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
Lost connection.
```

This an issue of ssh too. I cannot ssh to another node from the current node.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Why do you need to perform that action?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere To copy some file that was only downloaded on one node and share it to other nodes. How do you copy file without the use of scp?

Comment: You shouldn't manage node like that. It's not a good practice with kubernetes.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere what else can you do to achieve that? Let's say you have an ETL deployed on the k8s cluster and you use persistent volume, the pod that got triggered to execute the ETL download the file, but only on the pod's node. Now issues happen and you want to debug and don't want to re-download the file, how do you make sure this time, it is a pod of that node with the file get called rather than other random node?

Comment: Use GCS as intermediary step to transfer files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can ssh to both the GCP nodes here is the step for you to be able to scp from node A to node B.

1. local> SSH to node A
2. nodeA> ssh-keygen -b 4096
3. nodeA> cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub   (then copy the public key content)
4. local> SSH to node B
5. nodeB> vi ~/.ssh/authorized_keys (add the copied public key from nodeA as a newline)

Now you can scp from nodeA to nodeB.